# Custom html form in FB.ui dialogue box

Tags: facebook, user-interface, dialog, fb.ui

Is it possible to use FB.UI to open a facebook dialogue box containing an HTML form which I want the user to complete?

When they click submit, the values should be posted back to my app.

My app is inside an iframe on a page tab, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, FB.ui is specific for the Facebook JavaScript SDK.  You will want to use jQueryUi's dialog.  See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Thanks. Now that Facebook have increased the canvas width, this is less of an issue and simple div overlays containing forms are the way I've been going. Previously they looked a bit squashed inside the narrow iframe.